# Two-column text layout with irregular inset

Tags: html, css

One picture worth a thousand words:

[image: layout]

How to implement this layout? I want text to flow freely from Column-1 to Column-2.

Note that inset width is greater than column width, so it "pushes" text in Column-1 a bit. Below inset Column-1 returns to normal width.

I want compatibility with latest releases of modern browsers (Chrome, FF). No IE is OK. Safari, Mobile Safari, Opera are desirable.

JS is OK, but I'd prefer a solution without it.

---

*Update about known dimensions:*

- I know width and height of whole "page".
- I know width and height of image.
- I know width of inset, but not its height (since there is additional caption text there).

---

*Update:*

Below is my test code. If I move inset out of columns div, it is displayed as "third column".

If inset is in front of the text, it is displayed in the left column at the top, clipped from the left side to the column width.

If inset is in end of the text, it is displayed in the right column at the bottom, clipped from the left side to the column width in Chrome, and overflowing to the left column in FF (without pushing its text).

I must be missing something... :-(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Column test</title>

<style type="text/css">

div.columns
{
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
}

div.columns p
{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="columns" style="width:800px">

<!-- BEGIN INSET -->
<div style="float:right; width: 500px; margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: #5a5a5a;">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc neque elit, mollis a vulputate ac, mollis vitae augue. Sed augue enim, congue ac laoreet hendrerit, ultricies a sem. Integer dignissim molestie erat quis lacinia.
</div>
<!-- END INSET -->

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc neque elit, mollis a vulputate ac, mollis vitae augue. Sed augue enim, congue ac laoreet hendrerit, ultricies a sem. Integer dignissim molestie erat quis lacinia. Nulla pellentesque sodales dolor, et egestas tortor ultricies et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc semper dui sit amet sem condimentum vitae molestie arcu cursus. Morbi rhoncus posuere gravida. Sed bibendum ullamcorper lectus, id mollis nulla pulvinar hendrerit. Mauris id est nulla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam tempor venenatis vehicula. Nam a enim justo, nec viverra sem. Vivamus faucibus ullamcorper lobortis.
</p>

<p>
Cras nulla ante, tincidunt non accumsan nec, adipiscing eget odio. Nam gravida ligula at elit interdum lacinia. Mauris condimentum justo venenatis mauris condimentum eu fringilla augue hendrerit. Duis eget enim et erat faucibus blandit et lobortis ligula. Integer felis justo, feugiat et scelerisque non, vehicula in urna. Aliquam dignissim tristique ornare. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam volutpat ullamcorper purus, ut auctor magna consectetur at. Aliquam vitae odio in lectus lobortis fermentum. Nunc tortor quam, luctus et consequat vel, fringilla at lorem. Cras ut molestie diam. In aliquet purus sed massa sagittis id dapibus est ultricies. Mauris sed laoreet est.
</p>

<p>
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer mollis dapibus tellus, at venenatis mi euismod quis. Donec quis ullamcorper nulla. Maecenas semper porttitor nibh, et porttitor ipsum convallis eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec est turpis, faucibus id venenatis ac, mollis ut risus. Nam tincidunt scelerisque lectus.
</p>

<p>
Donec euismod neque id est accumsan eu egestas tortor adipiscing. Curabitur tortor ante, mattis at ultrices vel, facilisis eu sapien. Nullam congue ipsum vel nisi condimentum quis condimentum turpis pretium. In aliquet imperdiet ligula, ut dictum lorem ultrices at. Quisque ac nunc arcu. Pellentesque egestas venenatis urna, in blandit purus ullamcorper at. Ut lobortis, nisi at pharetra consequat, est nibh interdum est, vitae tempor felis magna sed erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
</p>

<p>
Sed ligula felis, volutpat ac pulvinar a, porta sed felis. Aenean eu turpis nec magna mollis tincidunt quis vitae massa. Praesent faucibus nisl in leo rutrum gravida. Donec aliquet interdum vestibulum. Aenean faucibus posuere ornare. Donec sed velit id sem pulvinar faucibus ut tempor tellus. Donec ante justo, egestas eget venenatis vitae, tempor et nulla. Suspendisse dapibus pellentesque nulla sit amet tempor. Curabitur auctor, sem id ullamcorper ultricies, nisl tortor rhoncus lorem, eleifend ornare tortor ante vel lectus. Nunc lectus sem, ullamcorper vitae aliquam sed, volutpat eu justo. Nam et nisl est, dictum vestibulum dolor. Cras ipsum orci, vestibulum ac convallis a, laoreet in lorem. Aliquam at adipiscing lacus. Donec quis dui sed felis sollicitudin ultricies in vel libero. Donec tincidunt felis et metus mollis at congue elit molestie.
</p>

<p>
Ut posuere lobortis est, sit amet adipiscing neque vehicula eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam id fermentum felis. Aenean nunc neque, faucibus vel consectetur eget, ullamcorper ac est. Nulla sit amet metus sed erat fringilla lacinia. In at pulvinar sapien. Mauris volutpat scelerisque elit, quis lobortis orci imperdiet pretium. Ut facilisis interdum dapibus. Sed luctus dignissim blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sollicitudin ultricies tortor nec rutrum.
</p>

<p>
Quisque sed sollicitudin lacus. Quisque egestas interdum dui, eget gravida sem convallis in. Sed auctor justo et urna gravida tincidunt. Proin erat nibh, euismod et varius at, aliquam in diam. Nullam condimentum libero id libero pretium ac ullamcorper arcu luctus. Sed gravida mattis tortor sit amet accumsan. Etiam vitae consequat dolor.
</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the image with its caption in a separate CSS layer and "pinning" it into the right position, coupled with some DIV's underneath which take care of pushing the content out from under it?  Something like this:

In CSS:

```
#column1 {
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    background: #444;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#column1-spacer {
    float: right;
    width: 45px;
    height: 170px;
}
#column2 {
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #444;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#column2-spacer {
    height: 175px;
}
#imageWrapper {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 170px;
}
#image {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #888;
}
#caption {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<div id="column1">
    <div id="column1-spacer"></div>
    Column 1
</div>
<div id="column2">
    <div id="column2-spacer"></div>
    Column 2
</div>
<div id="imageWrapper">
    <div id="image">Image</div>
    <div id="caption">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Maecenas vel vulputate justo.
    </div>
</div>
```

In my Firefox, it produces this:

[image]

Comment: You split columns into two divs. This wouldn't do for me, unfortunately. I need text to flow freely from one column to another.

Answer (score -1):

[curtisdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818236/curtisdf) has answered the issue of the image placement but as far as flowing text freely from column 1 to column 2 the easiest way would be to use CSS 3 columns. You can make CSS 3 columns work in browsers that don't support CSS 3 by adding modernizer to your site.

Modernizer: http://www.modernizr.com/

CSS 3 Columns: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Comment: I was not able to do this with CSS3 columns — inset gets clipped by column width. Can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, Modernizr only informs me about feature support, it does not implement the missing features, so it is of little help here (unless I know how to implement the columns, which I obviously don't).